# Iterate Table and Do stuff over partitioned rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I have a table with the following records:**

```
Id  Partitioned SDDate
1   1   2014-01-01
2   2   2014-01-02
3   3   2014-01-03
4   4   2014-01-04
5   5   2014-01-05
6   6   2014-01-06
7   7   2014-01-07
8   1   2014-01-08
9   2   2014-01-09
10  3   2014-01-10
11  4   2014-01-11
12  5   2014-01-12
13  6   2014-01-13
14  7   2014-01-14
15  1   2014-01-15
16  2   2014-01-16
```

As you can see the records are partitioned from 1-7 and what I want to achieve is to insert records by this group into a temp table.
When the highest number of partition id is reached then start the insert again.
Thanks.

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 RC2

This is the code:

```
Set NoCount On;

--
Declare 
    @InputTable As DT_HorasExtras

--
Insert Into @InputTable
( HorasExtra, Fecha )
Values
(3, '2014-01-01'), 
(3, '2014-01-02'), 
(1, '2014-01-03'), 
(2, '2014-01-03'), 
(1, '2014-01-05'), 
(3, '2014-01-06'), 
(3, '2014-01-07'), 
(3, '2014-01-08'), 
(3, '2014-01-09'), 
(3, '2014-01-10'), 
(3, '2014-01-11'), 
(3, '2014-01-12'),
(3, '2014-01-13'),
(3, '2014-01-14'),
(3, '2014-01-15'),
(3, '2014-01-16')


Declare @Idx Int = 1, @InnerIncrementor Int = 1;

--
Declare 
    --
    @PartitionedId Int,
    @Fecha Date,
    @HorasExtra Int,
    @Id Int;

    --
    DECLARE IDs CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        Select 
            t.Id
            From utilsFilterAndPartitionHorasExtras(@InputTable) t

    OPEN IDs
    FETCH NEXT FROM IDs into @Id
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            --
            Select 
                @HorasExtra = t.HorasExtra,
                @Fecha = t.Fecha,
                @PartitionedId = t.Partitioned
                From utilsFilterAndPartitionHorasExtras(@InputTable) t
                    Where t.Id = @Id

            --
            print 'Particion Dia: ' + Convert(varchar(max), @PartitionedId) + ', Fecha: ' + Convert(varchar(max), @Fecha) + ', Horas extras: ' + Convert(varchar(max), @HorasExtra);

        --*** HERE I WANT TO INSERT RECORDS ONLY FROM PARTITION 1 TO 7
        --*** WHEN 7 IS REACHED START INSERT AGAIN
         insert into #tmpTable values(@Field1,.,,


        -- inc
        Set @Idx+=1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM IDs into @Id
    END
    CLOSE IDs
    DEALLOCATE IDs
```

**this is the output:**

```
Particion Dia: 1, Fecha: 2014-01-01, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 2, Fecha: 2014-01-02, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 3, Fecha: 2014-01-03, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 4, Fecha: 2014-01-05, Horas extras: 1
Particion Dia: 5, Fecha: 2014-01-06, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 6, Fecha: 2014-01-07, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 7, Fecha: 2014-01-08, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 1, Fecha: 2014-01-09, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 2, Fecha: 2014-01-10, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 3, Fecha: 2014-01-11, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 4, Fecha: 2014-01-12, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 5, Fecha: 2014-01-13, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 6, Fecha: 2014-01-14, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 7, Fecha: 2014-01-15, Horas extras: 3
Particion Dia: 1, Fecha: 2014-01-16, Horas extras: 3
```

Comment: what sql server are you using, what have you tried?  by "iterate" you make it sound like you intend to use a cursor--is that what you want?  Clarification, please :)

Comment: What do you mean "start the insert again"?  And, what database are you using?

Comment: Yes I used a cursor, also I used modulo operator inside witouth any success

Comment: This is quite unclear to me, do you want the temp table with the one row for every seven value, with the values in different columns, or something else? Please add the expected result for the temp table.

Comment: instead of cursor you can use recursive CTE.Here your requirement is not clear. like why you want to insert in temp table.how long you hv to keep inserting when max partitionid is reached.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a group id to these rows, then you can just subtract the partition from the id:

```
select (partition - id) as grp, t.*
from table t
```

If the `id` values really are not necessarily sequential, you can use `row_number()` for this purpose:

```
select (row_number() over () order by (id, partition) - id) as grp, t.*
from table t
```

This will identify each group.  I'm not sure what you mean by inserting them and starting over.

Comment: I have added the code, so you can apretiate what I mean with inserting